how to create a total multi group row in RDCL/Report Viewer in VB.NET
I'm Trying to create a total multi group row in RDCL/Report Viewer in VB.NET
Please guide me
Thanks
Code in FORM1
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Dapper

Public Class Form1
    Private Function CreateConnection() As String
        Return ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\GROUPROW.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    End Function
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using db As IDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(CreateConnection)
            If db.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                db.Open()
            End If
            'Execute query to get orderdetails and products data
            Dim query As String = "SELECT ITEM,PRICE,QTY,CATEGORY1,CATEGORY2 FROM ITEM"
            Dim list As List(Of ITEM) = db.Query(Of ITEM)(query, commandType:=CommandType.Text).ToList()
            Using frm As New frmPrintPreview(list)
                frm.ShowDialog()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class ITEM
    Public Property CATEGORY1() As String
    Public Property CATEGORY2() As String
    Public Property ITEM() As String
    Public Property PRICE() As Integer
    Public Property QTY() As Integer

End Class


code in frmPrintPreview
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms

Public Class frmPrintPreview
    Private _list As List(Of ITEM)
    Public Sub New(ByVal list As List(Of ITEM))
        InitializeComponent()
        _list = list
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmPrintPreview_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ITEMBindingSource.DataSource = _list
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        Me.ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
        ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent
        ReportViewer1.ZoomPercent = 100
    End Sub
End Class


Result From Code

Desired Result
With a highlight color for each group row in total
example : - color total for CATEGORY1 is the same for each
- color total for CATEGORY2 is the same for each
- color total below it has a different color
CATEGORY1 CATEGORY2    ITEM   PRICE  QTY
A1          A1-1       1000   12000  10
            A1-1 TOTAL               10
            A1-2       1001   15000  8
            A1-2 TOTAL               8
A1 TOTAL                             18
B2          B2-1       1002   25000  20
            B2-1 TOTAL               20
            B2-2       1004   30000  25
                       1005   30000  30
            B2-2 TOTAL               55
B2 TOTAL                             75
TOTAL                                93


